# Domain Masking For Multi Subdomains in a SaaS App

Tags: php, .htaccess, saas

I am setting up a SaaS application written in PHP. Now every user gets a subdomain.appname.com where subdomain is user's choice. So there can be subdomain1.appname.com, subdomain2.appname.com and so on.

I have setup the CNAME entry too as a user's domain so that subdomain1.customerdomain.com points to subdomain1.appname.com and when I try subdomain1.customerdomain.com it perfectly loads the subdomain1.appname.com with subdomain1.customerdomain.com in the address bar.

As soon as I hit any link in the app, the domain in the address bar changes to subdomain1.appname.com which is obvious because there is no htaccess rule yet. And that's where I need help..I suck at htaccess, so what should be the htaccess file like to handle domain masking and keeping user's domain in the address bar all the time.

Comment: hello deep, can you help me to build saas based website using php i have searched but not able to see any reference on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem here is not .htaccess, the problem are the links.

The application must output all links using the `hostname` actually used in the URL. It must not use a fixed application URL, but determine it dynamically.

Comment: Bravo..worked perfect by modifying the config file..no htaccess mess..Thanks Lorenz!

Comment: and is this type of sanitization for subdomain, domain is sufficient? $subdomain = filter_var($data[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $domain = filter_var($data[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
    $extension = filter_var($data[2], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);

Comment: It is probably sufficient for security, but it does not guarantee that the data entered is valid.